# Grouping A nested window clause with an aggregate in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I need to take the total sales, by brand, per month, for say, October. My data is found in 3 tables, calendar_sales_dim, sales_fact, and product_dim, with keys. I have managed to pull all of the tables and set them in an alias, and that works, but I'm having trouble with where to group and where/how to make a window function that aggregates the sales per month. errors, errors, errors.

```
SELECT a.sales_year,
       a.sales_monthofyear,
       a.sales_day_key,
       a.product_key,
       a.order_amount,
       a.brand_label,
       a.total_money_earned
FROM
  (SELECT a.sales_year,
          a.sales_monthofyear,
          a.sales_day_key,
          a.product_key,
          a.order_amount,
          a.brand_label
   FROM
     (SELECT sales_year,
             sales_monthofyear,
             sf.sales_day_key,
             sf.product_key,
             order_amount,
             brand_label
      FROM calendar_sales_dim
      JOIN sales_fact sf ON calendar_sales_dim.sales_day_key = sf.sales_day_key
      JOIN product_dim pd ON sf.product_key = pd.product_key) AS a)AS a
```

desired results: (for a given month)

```
    year | brand | total money earned
    2018  nike     5000000000
    2018  adidas   498000000
    2019  nike     30000000000
```

etc

Comment: Please add `sql` tag and also the name of the DB you are using, to help experts find your question.

Comment: Also, could you please post the definition of the 3 tables you are talking about, people answering your question would have to guess them from your query.

Comment: It is unclear why you need nested subqueries and a simple aggregate query should work. Also, avoid re-using aliases like *a*.

Comment: what would be an example of such a simple aggregate query? it doesn't seem simple to me. To get total_money_earned for each brand in a specific month of every year, I need to correlate a lot of information. I thiiink I need to use year as a partition and iterate through brands, correlating order amount per brand. I'm totally lost trying to make it work.